# Sigma 14.16 STS screen barely visible

Tags: bike-computer

Around 4 months ago, I bought a Sigma 14.16 STS computer for my bike. I rode around 2500 km since then. Everything work perfectly until yesterday, when the computer just (almost) stopped displaying. What previously was a normal display, now has a couple of lines which change when pressing buttons, indicating that something is happening there and the computer itself works, but I still can't see anything. The thing was never put into extreme conditions (never colder than -8, never hotter than +20), I didn't try to drown it (even though it is waterproof and I used it in rain), didn't smash it against the ground (it never fell). Just the screen started malfunctioning. Anyone else ever had such a problem? What could be a fix?

Comment: It sounds like your unit was defective or you broke it somehow. You need to talk to Sigma's tech support; I don't think there's anything we can do for you, here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Sigma's tech support.

Comment: Does it have a replaceable disposable battery?  like coin cells or an AAA cell?  If so try replacing it.   After a quick google, your unit has a rechargeable battery inside.   Leaving for generic advise but not applicable to you, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried switching to a new battery (2 new ones, for great measure). Neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several reason come to my mind:

1. The temperature at which you were using it. LCD displays get notoriously slow at low temperatures. You mention -8°, was it right then when this happened? Things should go back to normal at room temperature. The computer will still be working normally but the display literally freezes. The phenomenon is well known to people who own an early LCD wristwatch. They became unreadable in the cold.

   2. At low temperatures, the battery either 3V lithium CR-type cell or Li-ion rechargeable slow down because of chemistry slowing.
   3. If the battery is a CR-cell it might be reaching the end of its life. Your device may be new but the battery was already inside for a while when you bought the computer or the cell is faulty.Try replacing the battery.

But then since your device is quite new I'd advise you to take it back to shop who sold it to you as warranty is still applicable.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer since I guess it's a best one that can be given, given the generic nature of the question (unless someone had this exact same problem). In fact, the display seems to be getting better. Berhaps it will restore itselfs in a couple of days. I'm trying to heat the thing up to 30 degrees Celsius and it looks like it has some moisture inside - the vapor covers the inside of the screen. Perhaps it will recover itself, but I ordered a new one nonetheless. The device broke at around 0-2 degrees Celsius, not in -8.

Comment: @Zloj sounds like you should absolutely get a warranty replacement.  If its rated to be waterproof and isn't then that's a failing right there.